# Quickfix list not opening file

Tags: vim

I am trying to use the quickfix list in `gvim` for my grep searches. This is on Windows and I am using `grep` from Cygwin by setting the following in my vimrc file:

```
set grepprg=C:/cygwin64/bin/grep
```

The grep works fine when I do:

```
:grep -R 'LOG' **/*cpp
```

I see the first match and do `:copen` to open the quick fixlist. Once I am there and want to go to a match hitting enter does nothing. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl+W+Enter</kbd> opens a new window that is blank. How do I make it so that when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+W+Enter</kbd> it will open a window to the spot of the match?

Comment: Do you have `autochdir ` on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default Vim mappings in the quickfix window are just as you say `<cr>` and `<c-w><cr>` (as listed out in `:h :lwindow`).

If these maps aren't working there are a few problems that could be occurring:

- You have some mapping overshadowing the native Vim mappings. Check if you have any mappings for `<cr>` whilst in the quickfix window via `:verbose nmap <buffer> <cr>` and `:verbose nmap <cr>`. Do the same with `<c-w><cr>`.
- The results maybe being ignored. A good way to tell is if match is ignored the line will start with `||`. This is often due to `'grepformat'`/`'grepprg'` not being set correctly.

On a personal note I have found `grep` to be slow in the past and now use [ag the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or `git grep` via [Fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Ggrep` command.

For more help see:

```
:h quickfix
:h :lwindow
:h 'grepformat'
:h :map-verbose
```

Comment: Thank you! I had the || at the start of all the lines. I added set grepformat=%f:%l:%m  but that didnt help. I then added the -n command to set grepprg=C:/cygwin64/bin/grep.exe\ and that did the trick.